# Getting a value from a nested class in c++

Tags: c++, class

Please I am trying to print out the value of a nested class from the private access specifier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class cal{
    private:
        int a = 0;

    public:
        int setNum(int m){
            a = m;
        }
        void getNum(){

            cout<<"the number is: "<<a<<endl;

        }
        class area{
            public:
                int setMan(int z){
                    cal obj;
                    obj.setNum(z);
                    return 1;
                }
        };
};

int main(){
    cal::area obj2;
    obj2.setMan(200);

    cal obj3;
    obj3.getNum();
    '
    return 0;
}
```

`cal::area obj2;
obj2.setMan(200);` is to set 200 to the nested class area and into the function `setMan`, of which `setMan` which pass the same value to the `int setNum(int m){a = m;}` this will set the value of `a` to "200". Then I wanted to print out the value of `a` but it displays 0 instead of 200.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a nested class only provides a definition for a nested class. If you want to have a member of that class you have to declare it:

```
struct cal {
    struct area {};      // class definition
    area m_area;         // member
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int setMan(int z){
    cal obj;
    obj.setNum(z);
    return 1;
}
```

The object `obj` is a temporary auto object and would be destroyed when you return from the function. By the way, "set" functions should not return values, returning 1 is confusing.

If you wish to connect objects somehow consider the composition or aggregation. For example:

```
// ...
        class area{
            public:
                area(cal& obj) : obj(obj);
                int setMan(int z){
                    obj.setNum(z);
                    return 1;
                }
                cal &obj;
        };
// ...


int main(){
    cal obj;
    cal::area obj2(obj);
    obj2.setMan(200);

    obj.getNum();
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, that is just an artificial example, I don't see the reason you make `area` a nested class, the reason of setting values to `cal` from `area`, etc.